# Restricting Return Type Of Function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, class, generics, types, restrict

Let's say I have the following class.

```
class MyClass {
  firstMethod: (a: string) => string;
  secondMethod: (b: number) => number;
}
```

I want to create a function, which accepts this class as its first argument. This should inform the type of the return type of the second argument, a function. Regardless of structural typing, I hope to restrict the return type fields to be of those defined in MyClass. For instance:

Good:

```
myFunction(MyClass, () => {
  return {
    firstMethod: (a) => a,
    secondMethod: (b) => b,
  };
});
```

Bad:

```
myFunction(MyClass, () => {
  return {
    firstMethod: (a) => a,
    secondMethod: (b) => b,
    thirdMethod: (c: boolean) => c,
  };
});
```

The extra field should result in a type error. As should altering the types of `firstMethod` and `secondMethod`.

Right now, I'm trying unsuccessfully like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?strictPropertyInitialization=false#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-cHUAABqwoAASfgc3Rzisj3SqqcYLv8KDb6Lu-fHkd94ADmQAImvm5ER4fsZjQA).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
const myFunction = (a : MyClass): MyClass => {
  return {
    firstMethod: (a: string) => a,
    secondMethod: (b: number) => b,
  };
}
```

Comment: no it is not. For several reasons: 1. the argument needs to be the constructor of `MyClass`, not an instance. 2. `myFunction` returns void. 3. the list goes on. It doesn't seem like you actually read through the question above.